# Como resolver? RuntimeError: Images in list must all have the same dimensions // Lib face_recognition

Tags: python

Tive o seguinte erro ao trabalhar com a biblioteca face_recognition, ao usar  o código:

```
face1 = face_recognition.load_image_file('face1.jpg')
face2 = face_recognition.load_image_file('face2.jpg')
face3 = face_recognition.load_image_file('face3.jpg')


face_recognition.batch_face_locations(images=[face1,face2,face3], number_of_times_to_upsample=1, batch_size=128)
```

Deu o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\OneDrive\PythonProjects\ident_facial.py", line 32, in <module>
face_recognition.batch_face_locations(images=[face1,face2,face3], number_of_times_to_upsample=1, batch_size=128)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\OneDrive\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 149, in batch_face_locations
raw_detections_batched = _raw_face_locations_batched(images, number_of_times_to_upsample, batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\Samuel\OneDrive\PythonProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 132, in _raw_face_locations_batched
return cnn_face_detector(images, number_of_times_to_upsample, batch_size=batch_size)
RuntimeError: Images in list must all have the same dimensions.
```

Mesmo eu deixando a dimensão das fotos iguais, continua do mesmo jeito.
Segue o código inteiro :

```
import face_recognition
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt






def show_img(img):
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()



# CARREGAR IMAGEM
face1 = face_recognition.load_image_file('face1.jpg')
face2 = face_recognition.load_image_file('face2.jpg')
face3 = face_recognition.load_image_file('face3.jpg')


face_recognition.batch_face_locations(images=[face1,face2,face3], number_of_times_to_upsample=1, batch_size=128)
```

Comment: o que seu programa retorna se você imprimir `imagem.shape` pra cada imagem (face1, face2, face3)?

Comment: Olá Samuel, acredito que o erro é claro: _Images in list must all have the same dimensions._ Ou seja, as imagens possuem dimensões diferentes entre elas. Em outras palavras, tamanhos diferentes de largura e/ou altura.